# Module resolution not consistent with esm and non esm files

Tags: firebase, webpack

I have a project setup where I have a web app that rely on few Firebase SDKs that is Webpacked and served via webpack dev server.

From what I could gather without getting into too much details is that there is a final dependency that have both general index, and es2017 index files

[image]

there are intermediate dependencies that also have both, like the **app** and some that have only es2017 for example the **messaging**, and some only general index files.

The problem I have is that, and I have debugged for a very long time, from my application level when I import an intermediate dependency in different files, in some cases it takes the general index file, and in some the es2017 of the same library.

So in the error stacktrace here I am trying to initialize the messaging service of Firebase: (ignore for a moment the missing promise reject)

```
    at Provider.getImmediate (index.cjs.js:153)                     // in component lib 
    at Module.getMessagingInWindow (index.esm2017.js:1155)          // in messaging lib
    at new MessagingWrapper (MessagingWrapper.js:76)                // in my application 
    at FirebaseSession.push.56916.FirebaseSession.getMessaging (FirebaseSession.js:96)
    at PushPubSubModule_Class.<anonymous> (PushPubSubModule.js:118)
    at step (PushPubSubModule.js:63)
    at Object.next (PushPubSubModule.js:44)
    at fulfilled (PushPubSubModule.js:35)
```

When the messaging module is initially loaded it also accessed the component lib and uses the correct es2017 index file, but at a later point when I am trying to actually get the instance of the Messaging service it goes to the other general index file.

in all cases I use the import the same as in `import {somthing} from "@firebase/messaging"`

I never really had to worry about these things and might miss something fundamental, but this feels like a webpack bug in predetermine which module to load from the nested lib...

do you know of a way I could FORCE webpack to resolve es2017 index file?
or should I open a bug?

---

More details:

This is the transpiled code of my MessagingWrapper file:

[image]

line 71: goes to the correct es2017 index file in the messaging lib and the correct es2017 in the component lib

where as line 76: goes to the correct es2017 index file in the messaging

line: [image]

and here line 1155: actually goes to the **firebase/app** lib es2017 file to resolve the provider, comes back to line 1155 and then call to getImmediate which ends up in the  general index file in the component lib, as you can see below:

[image]

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@firebase/*` packages are internal and you shouldn't be importing them within your code as warned on each of their [npm directory listing](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@firebase/messaging). As you encountered, this can lead to issues with module resolution as you essentially skip the internal setup steps by accessing the internals directly.

Instead, use the public API interfaces via `firebase/*` (for the modular SDK on v9+ or legacy SDK v8 and lower) and via `firebase/compat/*` (for the legacy SDK on v9+).

Comment: you mean I should omit the @ from the imports?

Comment: @TacB0sS Pretty much.